How to change language via terminal only for one user?
I have access to one server which admin is set to Polish but I prefer to have Linux in English. Can I edit something to use the English language only for my account? I can only use SSH.
Thanks in advance.

This StackExchange Q&A suggest the way to do this (using GNOME DE) and this one using the command line.

Which version of Ubuntu is running? While the technique mentioned by @graham would be applicable with GNOME, a quick check of the XFCE  whisker menu (used by Xubuntu) shows something labeled Language support.

The above suggested link to StackExchange looks promising for a GUI situation, provided the desktop is GNOME.  The command line suggestion requires sudo, which implies it would apply system wide and that would probably not be welcomed by the Polish admin in this instance..
